# Apache (httpd) - You don't have permission to access

Tags: apache

I'm trying to run the below command from my linux server

```
curl -T helloworld.txt -u user:pwd http://<ip>/record/helloworld.txt
```

Not able to upload a helloworld.txt file to my http url

Error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /record/helloworld.txt
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) Server at <ip> Port 80</address>
</body>
</html>
```

httpd.conf:

```
Alias /record /usr/bin/Test/web/record
<Directory /usr/bin/Test/web/record>
    DAV On
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    EnableSendfile off
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
<Location "/record">
    DAV On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "user"
    AuthUserFile /usr/bin/Test/web/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    RewriteEngine off
</Location>
```

httpd error logs:

```
[Thu Aug 27 16:54:39 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Aug 27 16:54:39 2015] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as     context root:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Thu Aug 27 16:54:39 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper:    /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Aug 27 16:54:39 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Aug 27 16:54:39 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Aug 27 16:54:39 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) configured --     resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 27 16:56:41 2015] [error] [client <ip>] Unable to PUT new contents for /record/helloworld.txt.  [403, #0]
[Thu Aug 27 16:56:41 2015] [error] [client <ip>] (13)Permission denied: An error occurred while opening a resource.  [500, #0]
```

Comment: `(13)Permission denied` can you check your filesystem permissions for this directory? It should be owned by the apache / httpd user, and should have privileges to be written to.

Comment: yes its owned by apache -> 'drwsrwsrwt  3 apache apache' both web and record folder

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by setting SELINUX = permissive in /etc/selinux config file. reboot the server once the changes are made

Comment: What if SELinux is disabled and I get this error?